# Generic arguments not being enforced

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have the following custom NUnit constrains.  It will (when implemented properly) test is a given `DateTime` is equal to tomorrow.

```
public class TomorrowConstraint : Constraint
{
    public TomorrowConstraint()
    {
        Description = "Tomorrow";
    }

    public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<DateTime>(DateTime actual)
    {
        return new ConstraintResult(this, actual, true);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have given the Type parameter a concrete type, rather than a generic type.

The test below utilises it:

```
[TestFixture]
public class X
{
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        Assert.That("string", new TomorrowConstraint());
    }
}
```

I'm passing in a `string`, *not* a `DateTime`, however the string is passed to the method without any problems.

If I look at the type with `actual.GetType()` I can see that it is a string:  `{Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}`.

*How is this happening?*

I'd assumed that I would get an exception somewhere along the way?

Comment: You aren't constraining the typeof `actual` to `DateTime`, you are just naming the generic parameter to `ApplyTo` `DateTime`. It would work the same if you called it `T` instead. If you attempt to access any `DateTime` members on `actual` (beside those defined by `object`) you will get a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as I speculated and Lee confirmed, the line

```
public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<DateTime>(DateTime actual)
```

does not constrain the generic type to be `DateTime`. Instead, it just uses `DateTime` as the identifier for the generic parameter, like `T` in other situations. To actually constrain the generic type, you need to use the `where` keyword:

```
public override ConstraintResult ApplyTo<T>(T actual) where T : DateTime
```

... except that wouldn't work either, because a generic type constraint has to be an interface or non-sealed class, and `DateTime` is sealed. So I'm not sure if there's a way to get compile-time type safety for this using generics alone. What you could do is have another method that calls the `DateTime` version of that method and use that for your unit testing:

```
public ConstraintResult ApplyTo(DateTime actual)
{
    return ApplyTo<DateTime>(actual);
}
```

Comment: You're right, except for the `where` constraint.  You can't use `where` with values types (bar all `struct`).

Comment: @BanksySan That's because value types (structs) are implicitly sealed, which falls under what I said.

Comment: I mean you can't have `where T : DateTime`.

Comment: @BanksySan Did you read my second paragraph? I literally said that.